# Error when trying to open the syncml web site

Tags: syncml

When I try to open the address http://www.syncml.org then I received this message : `Bad Request (Invalid Hostname)`. My computer runs Windows XP Service Pack 3.
So why this error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya this error occur in my system also and i think it's on he most of them.
you can go to this link for syncml
http://www.openmobilealliance.org/tech/affiliates/syncml/syncmlindex.html#V11

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that is that SYNCML was a project which was being developed in collaboration with my telecom gaints (I was then working for NOKIA); as the software vendors were customizing the servers and the annotations, it was then decided to open up a open mobile alliance. Hence now we have the OMA which has companies that are involved in development and enhancement of the project.